# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'global_state'

Tags: python, easygui, global-state

For the small project I'm working on, I have to use the package `easygui` with `import easygui`. I believe I installed it correctly, but now I'm getting the error:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'global_state'

From my understanding, it has something to do with `easygui`. I tried uninstalling and reinstalling `easygui` for a possible fix, but no luck.

I'm installing version 0.3.5 through Ubuntu.

The traceback of the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
                             File "/home/jmarlin3/smallprojects/cartoon-project.py", line 2, in <module>
                              import easygui #allows us to pick any file from our system
                             File "/home/jmarlin3/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/easygui/__init__.py", line 34, in <module>
                                                                                from .boxes.button_box import buttonbox
                                                         File "/home/jmarlin3/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/easygui/boxes/button_box.py", line 18, in <module>
                                                                          import global_state
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'global_state'
```

Comment: Please try to provide a minimum reproductible example follwing this guide : https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Show at least the full traceback of the error as properly formatted text in the question.

Comment: @MichaelButscher Just changed it!

Comment: How are you installing it and which version are you installing?

Comment: @RandomDavis I'm installing version 0.3.5 through Ubuntu.

Comment: Help this make sense to me. The `easygui` package that you're seemingly using, and getting that error from, has a latest version of 0.97.0 ([link](https://github.com/robertlugg/easygui/tree/release_0.97.0)). I found another package, `easy_gui`, which isn't the one that generated that error, whose latest version is 0.3.5 ([link](https://github.com/zachbateman/easy_gui)). It seems clear that you're not using that package and yet you said you're using version "0.3.5". How are you getting the version number, and what exactly are you doing to install it?

Comment: @RandomDavis That's what my Ubuntu said when I installed it: "Successfully installed easy-gui 0.3.5". Do I need to look somewhere else to get know which version I'm using? Also, someone else helped me with my problem. Thank you!

Comment: Yeah that's the wrong library, the correct library has instructions in its repo to install tkinter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the problem is with your tkinter; in your python version try to import tkinter:

```
Python 3.8.10 (default, Jul 14 2021, 03:51:04) 
[GCC 8.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import tkinter
```

If something like '_tkinter' not found you have to install tkinter (to have it working properly!) to use easygui.
If you are using python2:

```py
sudo apt-get install python-tk
```

python3:

```py
sudo apt-get install python3-tk
```

And install easygui:

```py
pip install easy_gui
```

Comment: Like I said above: to use easygui you need the tkinter working!

Comment: Yep! That was it! I didn't realize it wasn't installed. Thank you!